# Escribir resultados a la derecha del valor escrito (con desplazamiento)

Tags: c#, textbox

Tengo el siguiente código. Son dos TextBox y un Button. Lo que pretendo hacer es escribir el número que ingresó el usuario
Funciona bien, pero tiene el error que sobre escribe el valor previamente escrito en el textBox y siempre muestra el último valor. ¿Cómo hago para que escriba un valor pero agregue un espacio y escriba a la derecha del valor ya escrito previamente en el TextBox?

```
        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    
            int aux,cont,digito,i,n,pot;
            n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            cont = 0;
            aux = n;
            while (aux>0){
               cont = cont+1;
               aux = (int)aux/10;
           }
           aux = n;
           for (i=1;i<=cont;i++) {
               pot = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10,(cont-i)));
               digito = (int)aux/pot;
               aux = aux-digito*pot;
               textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(digito) + " ";               
           }
        }
```

Comment: Vos queres eso en donde?

Comment: Eso lo quiero en un TextBox

Comment: si. perfecto.. en cual? yo supongo que es en textBox2.. sabias que la propiedad Text de un Textbox es un string como cualquier otro? por lo tanto, si queres concatenar cosas en un string, como haces?

Comment: Sí, quiero que aparezca en el TextBox2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solución debería ser concatenar el Textbox con el operador `+=`

```
textBox2.Text += Convert.ToString(digito) + " ";
```

Comment: Si, esa es la solución

Comment: Bien pero si lo quiero mostrar en un MessageBox ¿cómo hago?
Si le pongo += tira error

Comment: tenes que colocar esa concatenacion sobre una variable que la declares fuera del boton sino cada vez que hagas click se va a colocar en blanco.

Comment: Ahí me quedó bien.

Comment: Lo tuve que poner debajo del public partial class MainForm : Form { sino tira error.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna forma de desplegar los valores de i en un  MessageBox?

Comment: Te diria que realices otra pregunta, porque estas ingresando comentarios sobre la respuesta y seria otra pregunta diferente. y se ensucia tu pregunta y mi respuesta.